# spam detection using google prediction api

Tags: social-networking, spam-prevention, google-prediction

I am looking for example to build a spam detection service in a social network. For example: identify a user posted comment as spam on a social network site (such as facebook). I don't have any training data. Does the google API have its own training data set, that can help me identify spam in user posted comments. How does that work? I need something to seed the algorithm with